# Swift Spawing Random nodes Around the Frame

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I would like to have a nodes spawn outside of the screen and travel to the other side at a random spot(All four side of the frame, randomly choosing which side).

I am new to `Swift` and I don't understand how I would be able to achieve this or get the collision working for when that node hits the other side of the `frame` to add a point to my score.

Comment: What is your specific difficulty? did you try anything? If so, it will be helpful to post it.

Comment: Welcome back! This is really two questions. You may want to split this up into 1), how to spawn things randomly, and then 2), hit detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw with Fluidity's approach is you are going to find more enemies spawning on the corners then in the center.  To get a more uniformed spawn, you want to use a circle with the radius being your scene's width or height / 2 + sprite width or height / 2 (depending on what side of the scene is longest)

Now a prerequisite to this is everything needs to be anchorPoint(0.5,0.5),  even the scene.  This approach will work with anchorPoint(0,0), but that would require extra math to shift your circle (This is not necessary, you will find your life a lot easier if you kept anchor points all at 0.5,0.5)

```
func randomPosition(spriteSize:CGSize) -> CGPoint
{

   let angle = (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(360)) * CGFloat.pi) / 180.0
   let radius = (size.width >= size.height ? (size.width + spritSize.width) : (size.height + spriteSize.height)) / 2
   return CGPoint(cos(angle) * radius,sin(angle) * radius)
}
```

To use it:

```
let pos = randomPosition(mySprite.size)
mySprite.position = pos`
```

Now to go in the opposite direction, you just need to flip the signs of your coordinates

```
let oppositePosition = CGPoint(x:-1 * pos.x,y: -1 * pos.y)
```

Now scoring a point when it hits the other side of the screen is easy.  There is no need for any collision.

What you want to do is a sequence of actions

```
let move = SKAction.move(to:oppositePosition,duration:10)
let score = SKAction.run({score += 1})
let seq = SKAction.sequence([move,score])
sprite.run(seq, withKey:"moving")
```

What will happen here is afte the sprite finishes its move action,  it will increase score.

Now I am going to assume if something collides with the object, then you do not score, so in your `didBeginContact`, remove the move action with `sprite.removeAction(forKey:"moving")`

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this is about *divide and conquer!* Just as in your shop question, you have a lot of steps to do, so spacing things out / keeping organized is the way to go!

I made a simple extension for SKScene to get a random X and Y based on the size and width... you can just put this in your gamescene if you want, but I put a lot of these reusable "helper" functions into their own file as SKScene extensions.

Second, we have an enum called `Side` that is used to:

- Provide the actual data for which side we want to perform operations on
- The logic for determining which random values we will need to spawn an enemy, and determine its destination
- Generate a random side
- Generate an opposite side

And finally our gamescene, which only has one function `spawnEnemy`... This is cool because it keeps your GS uncluttered and organized! Which is always great for when you are trying to implement a new feature / debug an old one.

```
extension SKScene {

  /// Something that could be useful in many scenes / games:
  func getRandomWidthHeight() -> (width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
    // A little confusing but we have to do two casts because
    // I misplaced my random function that uses Floats :)
    var randX = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.width)))
    var randY = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.height)))

    // We need to subtract where the anchorPoint lies to fit into
    // SK's coordinate system when anchorPoint == (0.5, 0.5).
    // In other words, if scene height is 1000 pixels, then 
    // the highest Y value is 500, and the lowest Y value is -500.
    // Because, 1000 * 0.5 (anchorpoint) is 500.
    randX -= size.width * anchorPoint.x
    randY -= size.height * anchorPoint.y

    return (randX, randY)
  }
}

enum Side {

  case left, right, top, bottom

  /// Used for finding enemy destination:
  var opposite: Side {
    switch self {
    case .top:    return .bottom
    case .right:  return .left
    case .bottom: return .top
    case .left:   return .right
    }
  }

  /// Used for spawning enemy, and for finding its destination:
  func getRandomPoint(inScene scene: GameScene) -> CGPoint {


    let (randX, randY) = scene.getRandomWidthHeight()
    /*
                         top: randX, maxY
                         ______
     left: minX, randY   |    |
                         |    |   right: maxX, randY
                         |____|
                     bottom: randX, minY
     */

    switch self {
    case .top:    return CGPoint(x: randX,             y: scene.frame.maxY)
    case .right:  return CGPoint(x: scene.frame.maxX,  y: randY           )
    case .bottom: return CGPoint(x: randX,             y: scene.frame.minY)
    case .left:   return CGPoint(x: scene.frame.minX,  y: randY)
    }
  }

  /// Simply create a random side to be used for spawning:
  static var random: Side {
    // 0 is top, 1 is right, 2 is bottom, 3 is left
    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))

    switch rand {
    case 0: return .top
    case 1: return .right
    case 2: return .bottom
    case 3: return .left
    default: fatalError()
    }
  }
}


class GameScene: SKScene {

  func spawnEnemy(speed: TimeInterval) {

    let sideToSpawnOn = Side.random
    let spawnPosition = sideToSpawnOn.getRandomPoint(inScene: self)
    let destination   = sideToSpawnOn.opposite.getRandomPoint(inScene: self)

    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    enemy.position = spawnPosition

    // Shift outside frame:
    enemy.position.x += (spawnPosition.x > 0 ? enemy.size.width  : -enemy.size.width)
    enemy.position.y += (spawnPosition.y > 0 ? enemy.size.height : -enemy.size.height)

    enemy.run(.move(to: destination, duration: speed))
    addChild(enemy)
  }

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([.wait(forDuration: 2), .run( { self.spawnEnemy(speed: 2) } )])
    run(.repeatForever(sequence))
  }
}
```

---

I didn't go over hit detection as that is a separate question :)

Comment: You are using maxX and maxY in your random, if this scenes anchorPoint is 0.5,0.5, wouldn't that make maxY at 500?  Lets say we randomly get 500. Then you take height of 1000/2 giving 500, and subtracting from 500.  This means the your range is -500,0

Comment: Also he wants to spawn outside the frame. You are spawning on the frame,  you may want to push back some

Comment: your range is still off, you need to be finding a random number of the entire width/height, then shift it by 1/2

Comment: unless your scene anchor point is (0,0), which is no longer the default

Comment: @Knight0fDragon crap I did put maxX and maxY there for some reason. was supposed to be `size` :P. I guess my ap was 0 when i tested

Comment: also, I would put the shift inside the function, this way you do not need to shift it every time you call the function

Comment: @Knight0fDragon lmao i am literally doing that now before you wrote that

Comment: @Knight0fDragon ok it's working for realz this time ty :P

Comment: There I helped you out, got rid of that ugly assert LOL

Comment: @Knight0fDragon HEY ASSERTS ARE MY FRIEND. or did you just guard?

Comment: I am not sure if you know this, but assert only works in debug mode, it is ignored on release

Comment: @Knight0fDragon isn't there a stronger assert? Or a mode to have them fail in release? Thought there was.

Comment: You do not want your app crashing in release mode

Comment: @Knight0fDragon i think it would be fun to make a game where the penalty of losing is the app crashing... then you must force the player to sit through a long opening sequence of titles and story to play again.